# How to select lines and reformat command output?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Is there a way to format the following output so that only lines 1 and
4 print out? It would be best if the first line and fourth line could
come out on the same line like this:

`sw pool test`*(no bracket)*`status up`

Example command and output:

- command:

  ```
  show server pool
  ```
- output:

  ```
  sw pool test {
  members 1
  ip_addr 200.200.200.111
  status up
  ```

Desired output formatting (note that the curly bracket that was at the
end of line 1 should be removed):

```
sw pool test status up
```

How can I get this output, preferably using awk?

Answer (score 2):

### Using awk

This prints the first line without `{` and the fourth line:

```
$ show server pool | awk 'NR==1{sub(/{/, ""); printf "%s",$0} NR==4'
sw pool test status up
```

#### How it works

- `NR==1{sub(/{/, ""); printf "%s",$0}`

  The condition `NR==1` selects the first line.  For this line, the `{` is removed with the `sub` command and then the line is printed using `printf` (without a trailing newline).
- `NR==4`

  The condition `NR==4` selects the fourth line.  Since no action is specified for this condition, `awk` does the default action which is. just as we want, to print the line.

### Using sed

The same thing is possible with `sed`:

```
$ show server pool | sed 'h;N;N;x;N; s/{\n//'
sw pool test status up
```

#### How it works

- `h`

  This saves the first line in the hold space.
- `N;N`

  This reads in lines 2 and 3.
- `x`

  This swaps the hold and pattern space.  This puts line 1 back in the pattern space.
- `N`

  This reads in the next line, line 4, into the pattern space, appending it to line 1.
- `s/{\n//`

  This removes the brace and newline from the end of line 1 so that line 1 and line 4 are now merged with brace removed.  This is what is printed.

Comment: That's great! I just tried and ran into a few unexpected snags but your tutorial was perfect. I will post one more question to maybe handle the snags I ran into. Thank you.